# How do I validate an input requiring two hex characters?

Tags: c#, validation, textbox, maskedtextbox

I want to validate a string value from textbox.

Validation requirements are:

1. Exactly 2 characters
2. Hex characters only

How can I do this?

Comment: are you wanting to convert a string value to hex or trim an existing hex value..?

Comment: Not conversion.I want to do validaiton to getting to characher which in range 00-FF

Comment: I can get two charcater it is okey ,but the range is problem

Comment: UInt unsigned it's your best bet would be to parse out each char within the string...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Regex validator control with the expression: `^[0-9A-F]{2}$`

Comment: by the way, if you want to allow lowercase, you'll need to account for that as well: ^[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}$

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression, something like:

```
^([0-9A-F]{2})$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
             String^ temp = "012345679abcdefABCDEF";
             if (temp->IndexOf(e->KeyChar) == -1)
             {
                 e->Handled = true;
             }
```

use this for hex character control

Answer (score 0):

//Use this method and before calling it ..pass or parse out the string.Substring(0,2)

```
public string ConvertToHex(string asciiString)
{ 
    var newasciiString = Substring(asciiString,0,2);
    string hex = "";
    foreach (char c in newasciiString)
    {
        int tmp = c;
        hex += String.Format("{0:x2}", (uint)System.Convert.ToUInt32(tmp.ToString()));
    }
    return hex;
}
```